# How to displaying data in GridView while columns already defined in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

Please support me to fixed my problem.
I have gridview in asp.net, and I've already defined the columns manually.
When i try to bind the data to gridview, the rows is adding but the data is not shown up.

And, I've tried to put another gridview without me adding the columns though
and bind the data to it, then boom! the data was shown up!

What's wrong with my code?
here is my code

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, db.con);
OracleDataAdapter cmd_adap = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

cmd_adap.Fill(dt);
Grid_Data.DataSource = dt;

Grid_Data.DataBind();
db.Close();
```

Comment: the code is correct, but [ I've already defined the columns manually ] this is wrong. <asp:BoundField DataField=""> DataField must match with your query output's column name

Comment: thanks for your reply! anyway.. I've already solved it. I'm not defined the column manualy but modify the columns inside C# query.